# Taxi - A stochastic Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Consider the following problem. A small taxi company has two taxis that each have been distributed to separate halves of a city. If a person orders a taxi, then the taxi that is distributed to that part of the city will come; unless that taxi is already occupied and the other is free, then the other taxi will take the passenger. If both taxis are occupied, then some other taxi company will take care of the passenger and we simply ignore them.

Say that we know that calls from part $1$ and $2$ of the city arrive randomly and time independently with rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Suppose also that the service times of the taxis are random independent and exponential distributed. The means of the service times are given by $\mu_{11}$, $\mu_{12}$, $\mu_{21}$, and $\mu_{22}$. Here $\mu_{ij}$ is the mean service time of taxi $i$ (i.e. the taxi that is distributed to part $i$ of the city) to handle the request from part $j$ of the city.

My question is then

> What simple stochastic process best describes this problem?

In particular I want to be able to answer the questions

> What is the probability that a taxi is free when a customer calls? What is the probability that a customer from part $i$ of the city will be serviced by the taxi that is distributed to part $i$?

First I thought of the problem as a queueing problem with $2$ servers, however that changed as I realised that we don't have a queue, we simply ignore customers if both taxis are occupied.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's a CTMC with $3\times 3$ states (with $3$ states per cab).

Comment: @A.S. Thank you for the help. I assume you mean continuous time markov chain. You say three states, I guess those would be serving part 1, serving part 2, and not occupied right?

Can you help me a little on how I then answer the posed questions? I haven't worked much with continuous time markov chains.

Comment: Right. At every moment, chances of both $C_1$ and $C_2$ changing states are negiligible. Hence you have $2-4$ possible transitions out of each state ($1-2$ per cab) with rates given by your parameters. These will form matrix $Q$. Solve $\pi Q=0$ to find stationary distribution which will answer all your questions (in steady state). Read Wikipedia for general overview. Non-steady state will require exponentiating $Q$- slightly messier.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this problem is using a Continuous Time Markov Chain. Since time is continuous the probability of two events happening at the same time is basically 0. If we represent the state of the system as $X_{i,j}$ with i and j being 0, 1 or 2, i = first taxi, j = second taxi, the number is 0 when the taxi is not serving, else it represents which part of the city it is serving. Now you can build equations to calculate the stationary distribution, which calculates the limiting probability that the system is in a specific state. These equations are built by equating the rate in and out of a state plus a normalizing equation that says all the probabilities sum up to 1. Here is a picture:

[image]

I'll give two of them here:

$(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\pi_{00}=\mu_{12}\pi_{20}+\mu_{21}\pi_{01}+\mu_{11}\pi_{10}+\mu_{22}\pi_{02}$

$(\mu_{12}+\mu_{21})\pi_{21} = \lambda_2\pi_{01}+\lambda_1\pi_{20}$

...

$\pi_{00} + \pi_{01} + \pi_{02} + \pi_{10} + \pi_{11} + \pi_{12} + \pi_{20} + \pi_{21} + \pi_{22} = 1$

Once we have the limiting distribution $\pi$ we can answer your questions.

The probability that a taxi is free is all the $\pi_{ij}$ with $i=0$ or $j=0$ summed up.

The probability that a customer is helped by the corresponding taxi (for district 1):

$P($Customer district 1 picked up by taxi 1$) = \frac{\pi_{10}+\frac{1}{2}\pi_{11}+\pi_{12}}{\pi_{10}+\pi_{11}+\pi_{12}+\pi_{01}+\pi_{21}}$

This last equation only works because of the PASTA property.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for the answer. Can you elaborate a little on how you get equation
$$(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)\pi_{00} = \mu_{12}\pi_{20} + \mu_{21}\pi_{01} + \mu_{11}\pi_{10} + \mu_{22}\pi_{02}? $$

Comment: I don't have enough karma to post a picture, but I drew a diagram with all the possible states, with arrows that represent possible state changes. For example (0,0) goes to (1,0) with rate $\lambda_1$, to (0,2) with rate $\lambda_2$ but it cannot go to something else. If you do this for all possible state changes, you pick a state, sum the outgoing rates multiplied by $\pi_{ij}$ and equate this to all the rates coming in. You need to do this for all but 1 of the states and use the normalizing equation to solve the system.

Comment: Added a picture that should make things clearer, if this solves your problem can you accept it as answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It will just take some time for me to understand everything, but  if it solves my problem I will of course accept :)

Comment: Did you solve the linear system? Is this set of equations correct?
\begin{align*}
(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)\pi_{00} &= \mu_{12}\pi_{20} + \mu_{21}\pi_{01} + \mu_{11}\pi_{10}+\mu_{22}\pi_{12}\\
(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\mu_{11})\pi_{10} &= \lambda_1\pi_{00}+\mu_{22}\pi_{12}+\mu_{21}\pi_{11}\\
(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\mu_{12})\pi_{20} &= \mu_{22}\pi_{22}+\mu_{21}\pi_{21}\\
(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\mu_{21})\pi_{01} &= \mu_{11}\pi_{11} + \mu_{12}\pi_{21}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: and these
\begin{align*}
(\mu_{11}+\mu_{21})\pi_{11} &= \lambda_1\pi_{10} + \lambda_1\pi_{01}\\
(\mu_{12}+\mu_{21})\pi_{21} &= \lambda_1\pi_{20}+\lambda_2\pi_{01}\\
(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\mu_{22})\pi_{02} &= \mu_{11}\pi_{12} +\lambda_2\pi_{00} + \mu_{12}\pi_{22}\\
(\mu_{11}+\mu_{22})\pi_{12} &= \lambda_1\pi_{02} +\lambda_2\pi_{10}\\
(\mu_{12}+\mu_{22})\pi_{22} &= \lambda_2\pi_{20}+\lambda_2\pi_{02}
\end{align*}
and of course the normalizing equation. Do I simply choose $8$ of these equations and the normalizing? I seem to get different answers depending on what I choose.

Comment: I did not end up solving the system of equations, you can just remove one and add the normalizing equation, it should give you the same answer. Try to express all the $\pi$'s in terms of one, for example $\pi_{11}=C\pi_{00}$. I have to go to bed now, I have a stochastic modelling test tomorrow, but if you haven't figured it out tomorrow I'll try and solve it completely.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've tried a lot of things, and the weird thing is I get slightly different results depending on which equation I remove. So I think I must've done something incorrectly.

Comment: The couple I checked matched the picture, maybe check my picture for mistakes as well.

Comment: Have you tried solving the system? I've tried a lot of things and I simply can't get something that seems correct.

Comment: I checked the equations and the picture and that looks good, I don't have the time to solve this at the moment, since it is a decently sized system of equations I would solve it using linear algebra, putting everything to one side, remove one, add normalizing one, multiply it by transposed vector $p$ and equating it to $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)^T$